# Ant Mac OS X Appbundler current directory path issues

Tags: java, macos, ant, app-bundle, working-directory

I'm trying to compile a Java application into a Mac OS X app bundle. I add the following setting to set the current working directory:

```
<bundleapp...>
    ...
    <option value="-Duser.dir=$APP_ROOT/Contents/Resources"/>
</bundleapp>
```

In Contents/Resources/ there is a config directory.

When executing it, I get this strange behaviour :

`new File("config/").exists()` returns false

`new File("config/").getAbsolutePath()` returns /path/to/bundled/app/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/config

`new File("config/").getAbsoluteFile().exists()` returns true

I don't know why this happens and I would like to prevent adding getAbsoluteFile() everywhere in my code.

Any thoughts on this?

(Note: I'm using Oracle JDK 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAbsolutePath` resolves relative paths against current `user.dir` property. From [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()):

> On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it
>   against the current user directory.

Although [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()) states that

> By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative
>   pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named
>   by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in
>   which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

[this bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;:YfiG?bug_id=4483097) states that "simpler" getters (not "absolute")
for relative paths will resolve against
the  path the virtual machine was invoked.

Comment: Would you know if there is another way to do this? If I add: <key>WorkingDirectory</key><string>$APP_ROOT/Contents/Resources</string>, it does not seems to help. I would like to prevent adding getAbsoluteFile() everywhere since the problem only occurs with the Mac application bundle...

Comment: Maybe the way to go is to set a final static field with the absolute path to the "Resources" folder. Then create `File` objects with the absolute path `File config = new File(ResourceFolder+"config")`.

Comment: You may be right, but it would have been simpler to change the current working directory... But thank you for your suggestion!